# Change top constraint constant value dynamically of a view - ios

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Using autolayout I want to change top constraint constant value dynamically of a view to show 10 points gap in iPhone 5 and 20 points gap in iPhone 6S from top without using code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to accomplish this only with interface builder tools, isn't it?

So that device specificity **can't be set on interface builder**, constraint variations are limited, take a look on how all iPhone share the same width and height constraint values.

[image]

Comment: yes want to accomplish this only with interface builder tools.

Answer (score 0):

No, You **cannot** achieve this without using code.

You can either subclass NSLayoutConstraint or create an IBOutlet of that constraint and set it programatically.